# Не могу сделать Lazy Load в Angular5

Tags: angular-routing, angular4

Не могу сделать Lazy Load в Angular5.Использую Webpack.В консоли ошибка следующего вида, хотя пути указаны правильно
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './modules/recipient/recipient.module'.
Error: Cannot find module './modules/recipient/recipient.module'.
Прилагаю файлы модулей

```
----app.module.ts----------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule, LoadChildren } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GroupListComponent } from './group-list.component';
import { GroupCreateComponent } from './group-create.component';
import { GroupEditComponent } from './group-edit.component';
import { RecipientComponent } from './modules/recipient/components/recipient.component';
import { RecipientModule } from './modules/recipient/recipient.module'

// определение маршрутов
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: GroupListComponent },
    { path: 'create', component: GroupCreateComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: GroupEditComponent },
    {
        path: 'recipient', component: RecipientComponent,
        loadChildren: './modules/recipient/recipient.module#RecipientModule'
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent, GroupListComponent, GroupCreateComponent, GroupEditComponent, RecipientComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})    
export class AppModule { }



 ----recipient.module.ts-----
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipientComponent } from './components/recipient.component';
import { RecipientCreateComponent } from './components/recipient-create.component';
import { RecipientEditComponent } from './components/recipient-edit.component';

// определение маршрутов
const recipientRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: RecipientComponent },
    { path: 'create', component: RecipientCreateComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: RecipientEditComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forChild(recipientRoutes)],
    declarations: [RecipientComponent, RecipientCreateComponent, RecipientEditComponent],
    bootstrap: [RecipientComponent]
})

export class RecipientModule {}
```

введите сюда код

Answer (score 1):

Решение такое - в командной строке выполнить

```
npm install angular-router-loader
```

Затем добавить в Webpack в секцию loader:

```
'angular-router-loader'
```

и все работает